# yasnippet how to debug?

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

I'm using some snippet I found from the internet.

And I encounter lots of error when using them.

for example,

```
printf ("${1:%s}\\n"${1:$(if (string-match "%" text) "," "\);")
}$2${1:$(if (string-match "%" text) "\);" "")}
```

This is a printf snippet for c mode. 
But it always gave me `[yas] elisp error! Symbol's value as variable is void: text`

So is there any bug in this piece of code or bug at somewhere else?
If so, how can I debug it?

Comment: Is the percentage a special character that needs to be escaped?

Comment: yas is clearly evaluating part of the snippet as an elisp expression -- it looks as if the syntax is `$(expr)` -- and there is no variable `text` when `(string-match "%" text)` is evaluated. Why did you use that variable name, and what do you believe it should be set to? A pointer to some documentation would probably be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the snippet you are using was written for older versions of `yasnippet` because the variable `text` was renamed to `yas-text` in newer versions, try replacing `text` with `yas-text` in the snippet.

I case you are not aware you can use `yas/tryout-snippet` to quickly try out snippets while editing them.